# Hi, I am trying to add weekstart column

Tags: python, pandas

In my current table I am having date column and from that column I am able to find out weekday.By using to_timedelta I have created week_start column but it is not giving correct date.
Here the code is:

```
final_data['weekday'] = final_data['DateOfInvoice'].dt.weekday

final_data['Weekstart'] = final_data['DateOfInvoice'] - pd.to_timedelta(final_data['weekday'],unit='ns', box=True, coerce=True)
```

output is as:

```
 Date       weekday   weekstart
2016-07-23  5         2016-07-22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can construct a TimedeltaIndex and subtract from the other column:

```
In [152]:
df['weekstart'] = df['Date'] - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['weekday'], unit='D')
df

Out[152]:
        Date  weekday  weekstart
0 2016-07-23        5 2016-07-18
```

in fact the weekday column is unnecessary:

```
In [153]:
df['weekstart'] = df['Date'] - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['Date'].dt.dayofweek, unit='D')
df

Out[153]:
        Date  weekday  weekstart
0 2016-07-23        5 2016-07-18
```

Comment: Thank you so much...it works..as I am very new in python, I got stuck in another problem. If you could help me I can solve the task given by manager...

Comment: If you have a new problem please post a new question, answering questions in comments is not good practice on SO